# We can't add this item to your shopping cart right now

Tags: magento2

I have a strange problem.

When I am logged and try to add an item to the cart I receive an error message (We can't add this item to your shopping cart right now. logged).

if i try when unlogged it work perfectly.

```
 /vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache/Backend
and edit the file.php
```

***Search for***

```
'cache_dir' => null,
 and replace it with
'cache_dir' => 'var/cache',
```

Not work after replace this code

**How can i solve the problem?**

Comment: Can you please check your **var/log/exception.log** file and check there is there any errors related to database Query or any third party extension ?

Comment: @Kishan Savaliya Ok Wait

Comment: @Kishan Savaliya 

[2019-11-04 05:25:30] main.CRITICAL: Validate class not found from basename 'Magento\Framework\Validator\EmailAddress' {"exception":"[object] (Zend_Validate_Exception(code: 0): Validate class not found from basename 'Magento\\Framework\\Validator\\EmailAddress' at /var/www/vhosts/harryepstein.com/staging.harryepstein.com/defaultmag/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Validate.php:244)"} []

Comment: Which magento version you're using ?

Comment: Magento ver. 2.3.0

Comment: Can you please check this file is available in your vendor directory ?  **vendor/magento/framework/Validator/EmailAddress.php** ?

Comment: @KishanSavaliya Yes this is available

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100664/discussion-between-kishan-savaliya-and-ranjeet-singh).

Comment: can you help me plz

Comment: Click on chat link

Comment: @Kishan Savaliya Hello sir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using **PLESK PHP** then you need to change this settings.

Plesk includes per default some wired zend directories ..
In the option "include_path"

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here you need to change **include path**.

Ref : https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/10821#issuecomment-334525946

Hope this will work for you!

Comment: Thank you so much its working

Comment: Can i do same thing to any other way likewise through .htaccess